# C# Raspberry pi Linux serial port permission denied even as root

Tags: c#, linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I am writing a program trying to communicate with serial ports of the raspberry pi. The program can find the device linked to the port. But when I want to open that port, it threw me an exception saying that the serial port can't be opened, permission denied. I logged as root(pi) and I think I added myself to "dialout". However nothing worked. What will be the problem of my situation? Hope there's any could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right device?

Comment: What do you mean by right device? I can find the name of the device, that should indicate the device was right, wasn't it?

Comment: Make sure you have read write privileges to the serial device. If not use chmod util to do that.

Comment: just cos /dev/xxx exists doesnt make it the right device file - but so far this isnt a c# issue

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you have to be a member of a specific group.